# React custom compnent css modules vs global css

Tags: reactjs, sass, components, styles

I need to make a clarification here.
I have used sass for styling. I went along only with editing custom.scss file.
Say I create an enterprice level project,say E commerce site.
Is it a best practise or a convenient way to add component wise scss modules for each component?.
Say it is a huge site with so many components, is it good to have so many custom css or just use one css file?
I am a bit confused here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you have a large project, but you have components that you use **often**, it's worth styling them **individually**.

On the other hand, there is **general styling**, for example, the font or even the background. Here it is no question that this belongs in a **general stylesheet**.

Everything in between is always situation-dependent. I tend that if the component is well **capsulated**, style them **individually**.